# Rabbinical authority

Tags: rabbis, derabanan, halachic-development

I am delving into the concept of the rabbinical authority based on the following [pasuk](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> "If a case is too baffling for you to decide, be it a controversy over
> homicide, civil law, or assault—matters of dispute in your courts—you
> shall promptly repair to the place that the L-RD your G-d will have
> chosen" [...] You shall act in accordance with the instructions given
> you and the ruling handed down to you; you must not deviate from the
> verdict that they announce to you either to the right or to the left.

Based on this, I have the following question:

1. The Torah states "If a case is too baffling for you to decide", does this means that you'll need to take a decision by yourself first, and then, when you do not know how to handle, "go to the place that the L-RD your G-d will have chosen"?  This seems to be what Rav Moshe Feinstein zt"l did, he wrote only a responsa after he delved with great effort in a particular halacha [(refer to his Hakdama on Igros Moshe, Chelek a)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&st=&pgnum=4).

Comment: It seems appropriate to break this question up into several individual questions in keeping with the guidelines. You are broaching a whole range of ideas here. Just glancing over Rabbi Linzer’s article, a few important details seem to be getting lost. The source of our laws and how we understand them comes to us via the Law Giver, Moshe Rabbeinu. We learn the concept of Rabbinic authority via his semichah of his student, Yehoshuah, who filled Moshe’s place. Court interpretation only comes when there is dispute between litigants. Otherwise, the is no Heavenly help to the Judges.

Comment: Continued: Another critical idea to keep in mind is that according to Jewish tradition, at least as we understand it from Sherirah Gaon, is that prior to Hillel and Shammai (the individuals) there was almost no disagreement over halacha among all Israel. Individuals might have a dispute over what applied. But what the actual laws were, was in agreement. That’s something difficult to imagine today. Good group of questions though.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thank you. I am aware of the Igeret Rav Sherira Gaon, haven't read it completely though. Any other recommendations to read on this subject?

Comment: Re link to Igrot Moshe, this idea comes from its introduction, see a translation [here](http://daattorah.blogspot.com/2021/08/introduction-to-igros-moshe.html), starting from "Since decisors of equal standing with those of earlier generations are not available today"

Comment: Thanks @mbloch. However, the pasuk states "if a case is to baffling for you to decide", implying that if it's not, you are able to pasken by yourself?

Comment: I meant to provide the source for the RMF's statement, not necessarily answer your question, because I don't completely understand it. To me it is clear. To the extent you have learned halacha, you should be able to answer a set of clear-cut cases. The more complex the case, the more you will need to study or ask a more learned or more experienced Rav. Once you reach the level of being able to pasken complex situations, you can do it yourself. Normally it comes after years of study and *shimush*, i.e., observing experienced rabbanim.

Comment: To give a sense of proportion, my Rav told me he learned 40 times portions of Yoreh Deah to feel comfortable paskening the most complex questions. At that level, there is no problem to "come with your own decision according to your best knowledge". Until then it is best to ask when things get complicated

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. This could me an answer, so if you want to give this as an answer, I would mark it as accepted.