# Rabbinical authority (2)

Tags: rabbis, derabanan, halachic-development

Part 2 of the question: [Rabbinical Authority](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/127191/27180):

I am delving into the concept of the rabbinical authority based on the following [pasuk](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.17.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "If a case is too baffling for you to decide, be it a controversy over homicide, civil law, or assault—matters of dispute in your courts—you shall promptly repair to the place that the LORD your G-d will have chosen" [...] You shall act in accordance with the instructions given you and the ruling handed down to you; you must not deviate from the verdict that they announce to you either to the right or to the left.

1. The Gemara teaches us that a Torah scholar may not teach halakha unless he receives permission from his teacher to do so. What does this mean, and how does this "fit in" with the pasuk mentioned above?
2. It is a principle to "follow the majority" (Shemos 23:2), but what if there are many different opinions among Rabbi's? Rashi explains this pasuk as " If you see wicked men wresting judgment do not say: since they are many I will incline after them", so, please correct me if I'm wrong, even if there is a majority, you should not incline after them if they are "wicked men". Should you then follow the minority?

Comment: That verse is referring to the majority of a beis din, esp. the Sanhedrin. After the Sanhedrin, the halacha can sometimes be decided in accordance with a minority opinion.

Comment: Okay, can you cite any sources to back up this statement?